# Issue with refactoring Javascript into a Class Object

Tags: javascript

I try to Refactor my Javascript Code into a Class Object javascript code, but I'm meeting some issues.

My old code which was working, was beginning like this :

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    // Variables :
    var color = "#000000";
    var sign = false;
    var begin_sign = false;
    var width_line = 5;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var cursorX, cursorY;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


    context.lineJoin = 'round'; 
    context.lineCap = 'round'; 


    document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
        sign = true; // Coordonnées de la souris :
        cursorX = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
        cursorY = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
    });
```

My new code begins like this :

```js
"use strict";
class Signature {
  constructor() {
    this.color = "#000000";
    this.sign = false;
    this.begin_sign = false;
    this.width_line = 5;
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.cursorX, this.cursorY;
    this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.context.lineJoin = 'round';
    this.context.lineCap = 'round';
  }

  init() {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
      this.whenMouseDown();
      this.whenMouseUp();
      this.whenMouseMove();
      this.createSignature();
      this.clearCanvas();
      this.resetCanvas();
    })
  }

  whenMouseDown() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", function({
      pageX,
      pageY
    }) {
      this.sign = true;
      this.cursorX = (pageX - this.offsetLeft);
      this.cursorY = (pageY - this.offsetTop);
    })
  }
```

But it seems that it's not correct.
How can I correct my code ?

Comment: Put the init code in the constructor where it belongs. Remove the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener as it is no needed. Will need to bind your event handlers to the `this` keyword. For this reason, it would be best to use function names as callbacks in your handlers rather than anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the class, it seems that you create instance of this class before the DOM is ready (I say that because of the contents of the `init` functions) which means that `this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');` will set `this.canvas` to `null`.

Beside that, you're also using normal functions for the event handlers and you're referencing the class' properties inside them.

Here is how I will do it:

```
class Signature {
  constructor() {
    this.color = "#000000";
    this.sign = false;
    this.begin_sign = false;
    this.width_line = 5;
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.cursorX, this.cursorY;
    this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.context.lineJoin = 'round';
    this.context.lineCap = 'round';
    this.whenMouseDown();
    ....
  }

  whenMouseDown() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", ({
      pageX,
      pageY
    }) => {
      this.sign = true;
      this.cursorX = (pageX - this.offsetLeft);
      this.cursorY = (pageY - this.offsetTop);
    })
  }
  ...
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
  new Signature();      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the commented code is for the unimplemented features from your code.

If you are looking for a traditional approach, this is the way to achieve your goal.

The `init()` has been moved to the constructor and a very clean approach is taken with the event handlers.

Given your approach (and that of the other answer), every time you click the mouse on the `document` you will create a new event handler that will be called on every mouse click etc.

Setting up your event handlers in the constructor prevents that.

```js
"use strict";
class Signature {
  constructor() {
    this.color = "#000000";
    this.sign = false;
    this.begin_sign = false;
    this.width_line = 5;
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.cursorX, this.cursorY;
    this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.context.lineJoin = 'round';
    this.context.lineCap = 'round';
    //    this.createSignature();
    //    this.clearCanvas();
    //    this.resetCanvas();
    this.whenMouseDown = this.whenMouseDown.bind(this);
    //this.whenMouseUp = this.whenMouseUp.bind(this);
    //this.whenMouseMove = this.whenMouseMove.bind(this);

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.whenMouseDown);
    //    this.document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.whenMouseUp);
    //    this.document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.whenMouseMove);
  }

  whenMouseDown(e) {
    this.sign = true;
    this.cursorX = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
    this.cursorY = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```